# How do I transfer the calendar entries from Windows Mobile to Android?

Tags: calendar, windows-mobile, data-transfer

Is there an easier way to transfer my calendar entries that does not involve Outlook? I have a .CSV file with all the entries in my current Windows Mobile calendar, but I'd like to migrate this to my Galaxy S 2 too.

Answer (score 3):

Easy if you have a google account.

Open google calendar on your PC and import the CSV file.

Calendar import functionality is in settings > calendar settings page.

Depending on your sync settings your android device will autosync entries.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Google account,you do not even need a .csv file.
You may [sync your WM phone with Google](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=138636) then when your Android mobile syncs, it will get the calendar entries.
This way you will have the two mobiles in sync and not just for calendar.